# Unable to Authenticate my Bitbucket server account with Sourcetree / How to register in source tree with Bitbucket Server credentials

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a Bitbucket repository, which I'm able to logging in web browser with my credentials, Now I want to checkout it in Sourcetree, So I've installed Sourcetree 2.6.10, It requires authentication to Bitbucket server with Root URL & Username to continue, I'm providing input in below format...

**Root URL :** https://bitbucket.xxxxxxx.com

**Username :** xxxxxx.xxxxxx

The error i'm getting is...
*Failed to check login for user [xxxxx.xxxxxx]. You do not have permission to access URL ‘https://bitbucket.xxxxxxxxx.com/rest/api/1.0/users/xxxxxx.xxxxxx’ please check the user credentials associated with this account. The request returned with status code ‘Unauthorized’.*

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Drop everything after ".com" and log in there.

e.g. log into
https://bitbucket.xxxxxxx.com

not

‘https://bitbucket.xxxxxxxxx.com/rest/api/1.0/users/xxxxxx.xxxxxx’

see also
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-8743

Answer (score 0):

To fix:

1-go to source tree window, clicked remote

2-little gear icon, clicked "settings"

3-double clicked on Bitbucket server, changed protocol from default HTTPS to SSH

Comment: You didn't get my point here, I'm not able to install and configure source tree, I'm bitbucket server user, not cloud. To be more clear, I've updated question as well.

Comment: While this may not have been an answer the question, it did help me resolve my issue, which was similar. So thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

To Perforce, Now, I m sharing another solution whether if the user prefers, BitBucket Cloud intergrated with SourceTree,(facing the above stated issue),

Since one of the steps of the upgrade process was to input your Atlassian account password, you should now have a password set (in addition to being able to use Google). You should be able to use your Bitbucket username and Atlassian account password to authenticate SourceTree.

If you need to reset your Atlassian account password, you can do so here: https://id.atlassian.com/login/resetpassword

Source : https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Cannot-login-with-Bitbucket-in-SourceTree-after-linking-with/qaq-p/145231

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to register Sourcetree the first time I opened it, using my company's Bitbucket Server URL. Turns out I just needed to include `https://` at the beginning of the URL.